# $_SESSION variable wont unset()

Tags: php, session

I have a $_SESSION array that i need to edit. For example please see the array below:

```
Array
(
    [first] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [quantity]=>24
            [name]=>fakename
        )

       [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 45
            [quantity]=>09
            [name]=>fakename
        )
        [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [quantity]=>14
            [name]=>fakename
        )
    )
)
```

So now lets say i want to remove the session with key of 2, i try to do:

```
unset($_SESSION['first'][2]);
```

This does not unset. Am I doing this right ?

Comment: does not unset HOW? did you check var_dump($_SESSION) before/after this operation? if it's gone after unset, but back again next time you load the page, then it's not an unset problem, and something session-related - e.g. maybe you did a `session_write_close()` previously, which means any $_SESSION changes won't get saved to storage anymore.

Comment: i print_r($_SESSION) at the top of my page. After performing this unset i reload the page as many times as i want and it does not unset. I also have not done a session_write_close()

Comment: However i do this through ajax, so it sends a request to a file where it unsets the session, do you think this could have something to do with it?

Comment: do a print_r AFTER the unset call.

Comment: i do , the print_r is at the top of my file so it displays everytime i reload the page

Comment: that's not what I'm saying. put it **AFTER** the unset, so you can see what the session array looks like after the unset. e.g. you're cutting a piece of cake, and someone replaces the cake with a fresh uncut one each time you turn around to put the cut piece on a plate. you're complaining about the cake not being cut, but you never bother checking if you actually cut it in the first place.

Comment: if the before/after WITHIN THE SAME execution run shows changes, but the data reappears on the next page load, then you'll know it's not unset's problem - something is resetting your session, or causing it to not be updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103117/discussion-between-matthew-smart-and-marc-b).